# how to connect to payment gateway

Tags: php, curl, payment-gateway, payment

i have a ready script that is encrypt and can not access to all codes.
this script have a payment gateway
in payment page is a form with action to a certain page

```
<form name="payment" method="post" action="example.com/cPage">
<input name="amount" id="amount">
<button type="submit">pay</button>
<input name="submit" type="hidden" value="1">
```

i change the action to my payment page: `action="example.com/.../mpage/send.php"`
and mpage is an api that i get from bank and have send.php, get.php and function.php
the problem is when i change the action to mpage gateway work but does not show in cms of script and only in default action payment money show in customer profile in cms.

function.php:

```
function send($url,$api,$amount,$redirect){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"api=$api&amount=$amount&redirect=$redirect");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $res;
}
function get($url,$api,$trans_id,$id_get){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"api=$api&id_get=$id_get&trans_id=$trans_id");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $res;
}
```

send.php:

```
    include_once("function.php");
    $url = 'http://bankwebsite.com/gateway-send'; 
    $api = '*****';
    $amount = $_POST['amount'];
    $redirect = 'http://example.com/.../mpage/send.php';
    $result = send($url,$api,$amount,$redirect); 
    if($result > 0 && is_numeric($result))
    {
        $go = "http://bankwebsite/gateway-$result"; 
        header("Location: $go");
    } else {
    print_r($result);
}
```

get.php:

```
include_once("function.php");
$url = 'http://bankwebsite/gateway-result-second'; 
$api = '********';
$trans_id = $_POST['trans_id']; 
$id_get = $_POST['id_get'];
$result = get($url,$api,$trans_id,$id_get); 
if($result == 1)
{#success msg
    }
else
{#failed msg
    }
```

now i add a newSend function to function.php:

```
    function newSend($url,$amount,$submit){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"amount=$amount&submit=$submit");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $res;
```

and this code instead of #success msg in get.php:

```
$url = "http://example.com/cPage";
newSend($url,$amount,1);
```

and it is not working.
i do not know how to send amount in two action that money written in cms and also payment be done.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand anything here.

Comment: in a simple explain i have a payment page that when action page in submit form is default, it writes the input amount in customer profile. and when i changed default page to api that i get from bank , money transfer but does not show in cms. i need to send amount value to two pages. default page for write to cms and bank api page for transfer money

Comment: Okay, so what exactly do you mean by "it is not working"? It is not working _how_? What _is_ happening? Are you getting errors? Are you getting an unexpected response? What debugging have you done? What is the value of `$result` in `get.php`? What is the value of `$res` in `newSend()`?